# JPA OneToMany relationship problems

Tags: json, jackson

It's a never ending story :)

I read a lot of posts and docs to this topic and I still don't really understand whats happening there.

I have a child:

```
@Entity
public class Offer implements Serializable {
...
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "provider_id")
    private Provider provider;
```

And the parent:

```
@Entity
public class Provider implements Serializable {
...
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "provider") 
    private List<Offer> offers;
```

If I call `providerRep.findAll()` it causes an endless loop.

If I remove the `mappedBy="provider"` It works. But I cant save Offers as a child of Provider.

How do I config it right? (without loop)

How do I saving a Offer as a child of Provider straight, without having to add it to Provider and save the Provider... (Is it even possible?)

The Workflow is easy:
I creat & save a provider. Then saving a lot offers for a provider. So no cascading.PERSIST is necessary.

Hope you can help me understanding my issue. Especially this "mappedBy" and JoinColumn point confuses me.

EDIT:

on calling offerRepo.getOne() :

```
2017-09-15 10:56:23.357  WARN 14128 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : 
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.Http
MessageNotWritableException: 
Could not write JSON: 
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: de.gaudiamo.content.entities.Provider_$$_jvstc64_7["offers"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag
```

Comment: an "endless loop" that you don't show. In JSON ? or in JPA ? because they are totally different APIs.

Comment: In JSON (Jackson). All I see is a endless stackstrace.

Comment: ...`  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
  at `...and so on

Answer (score 0):

try change @JsonBackReference to @JsonIgnore

Comment: Same result. It confuses me too. Meanwhile I removed all other values (just ID and the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

OK.. I found some kind of a solution. Opinions welcome!

Setup child:

```
public class Offer implements Serializable {
..
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "provider_id")
    private Provider provider;
```

and parent:

```
public class Provider implements Serializable {
...
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "provider", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}) //mappedBy= referenz attribute name in Offer
    private List<Offer> offers;
```

and POM:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

! Note that I switched `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` in child and parent ! (I am still not sure how this notations work under the hood)

Iam a bit afraid that I run into several problems later with this. 
Iam open for any hints.

Thanks
Gregor